# Storing arrays into database as Single Value - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send this array of values below to my database and i get the error

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given

**Array of values**

[image]

**Controller**

```
 public function store(Request $request, $user_id, $broker_id)
     {
         $get_item_id = $request->all();
         $store_item = $this->patient->store(array_merge($get_item_id, ['user_id' => $user_id], ['broker_id' => $broker_id ]));
         return response()->json(['success' => true, 'data'=> ['items' => $get_item_id)]],200);

     }
```

**Model**

```
protected $fillable = ['item_id'];
```

When i post the array as shown in the image to i get the error above..What could i be doing wrong in my code ?

PS: I am trying to store `item[0]` and `item[1]` into the database.

**New Code**

```
public function store(Request $request, $user_id, $broker_id)
         {
             $get_item_id = $request->all();
             foreach($get_item_id as $data)
             {
             $store_item = $this->patient->store(array_merge($data, ['user_id' => $user_id], ['broker_id' => $broker_id ]));
             }
             return response()->json(['success' => true, 'data'=> ['items' => $get_item_id)]],200);

         }
```

**Results**

The item_id column is empty and it only return one row..

Comment: What is in your `$request`?

Comment: @HazzAzimi `{"item_id":["1","2"]}`

Comment: Then you have to iterate over them like a loop and then store them because you are trying to store multiple rows. (which indicates you are doing something wrong)

Comment: @HazzAzimi, please check my update with the new code

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your for-loop to reflect the array you want to loop over

```
$get_item_id = $request->all(); // returns {"item_id": ["1", "2"]}
foreach($get_item_id['item_id'] as $data) // data will first be "1" then "2"
{
   // store the data
}
```

Comment: I get the error `array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array`

Comment: Are you sure in your updated code that `$data` is an array?